# Cannot open database "RidaDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'PLESK01\IWAM_plesk(default)'

Tags: sql-server, security

I have following message

> Cannot open database "RidaDatabase" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'PLESK01\IWAM_plesk(default)'.

Kindly assist in resolving this error , we tried but no luck.

Comment: Can you please specify if the error is for some .net app or for sql server database and what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Grant the necessary permissions on the database RidaDatabase to the user PLESK01\IWAM_plesk